# Hard-Drive not showing up in VMware vsphere

Tags: hard-drive, esxi

I have ESXi 6.0.0 running on an M5A97 LE R2 ASUS motherboard. Originally, I had ESXi installed on a 240GB SSD which ran out of space pretty quick.

So I picked up a Western Digital Black with 1 TB of storage. Plugged it in, annnnnnnnd it hangs during boot. It hangs after the screen says "iscsi_vmk loaded successfully"

I also believe that SATA is hot-swappable, so I also plugged in the drive while ESXi was turned on, but ESXi does not recognize the drive still.

Is there something I'm supposed to be doing in order to get ESXi to recognize that I installed a new drive? Is there a good log file that I can use for diagnosis? Any sort of leads would be really useful for me.

Comment: You only believe it's hot swappable?

Comment: Based on my google research, yes